# flutter gridview vertical filling

Tags: flutter

By default GridView puts items in row until crossAxisCount will not reach

```
   GridView.count(
       crossAxisCount: 5,
       mainAxisSpacing: 10,
       crossAxisSpacing: 10,
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
       children: hours
     )
```

[image]

Is there way to change build direction from horizontal to vertical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the scroll direction should do what you want:

```dart
 GridView.count(
       crossAxisCount: 5,
       mainAxisSpacing: 10,
       scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
       crossAxisSpacing: 10,
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
       children: hours
     )
```

Comment: This does nothing